# install gtk2hs with Darcs

Tags: haskell, gtk, cabal, gtk2hs

I'm having some existing code that I'm not able to run without gtk2hs. But I can't get it installed. I tried with cabal before but found out that the correct solution for now is to build from darcs. So I do :

```
darcs get --lazy http://code.haskell.org/gtk2hs
cd gtk2hs
export PATH=$HOME/Library/Haskell/bin:$PATH
sh bootstrap.sh
```

And get this :

```
Resolving dependencies...
Configuring gio-0.12.4.1...
setup: The pkg-config package gio-2.0 version >=2.16.4 is required but it
could not be found.
Resolving dependencies...
Configuring cairo-0.12.4.1...
setup: The pkg-config package cairo version >=1.2.0 is required but it could
not be found.
Resolving dependencies...
Configuring pango-0.12.4.1...
setup: At least the following dependencies are missing:
cairo >=0.12.0 && <0.13
Package has never been configured. Configuring with default flags. If this
fails, please run configure manually.
Resolving dependencies...
Configuring gtk-0.12.4.1...
setup: At least the following dependencies are missing:
cairo >=0.12.0 && <0.13, pango >=0.12.0 && <0.13
setup: Run the 'configure' command first.
setup: Run the 'configure' command first.
setup: Run the 'configure' command first.
Package has never been configured. Configuring with default flags. If this
fails, please run configure manually.
Resolving dependencies...
Configuring gtk3-0.12.4.1...
setup: At least the following dependencies are missing:
cairo >=0.12.0 && <0.13, pango >=0.12.0 && <0.13
setup: Run the 'configure' command first.
setup: Run the 'configure' command first.
setup: Run the 'configure' command first.
```

I'm on osx with most recent versions of cabal and darcs.

Comment: Do you have GTK installed? It looks to me like for some reason Cabal can't find the actual GTK libraries...

Comment: @MathematicalOrchid how did you found that? It's just that to me errors looks like nonsense, what does they trying to say? `The pkg-config package cairo version >=1.2.0 is required but it could not be found` — is it that pkg-config outdated? Or that cairo outdated? I.e. I am having GTK, but experiencing the same problem.

Comment: @MathematicalOrchid From the author's problem *(mine had only one error)* I can infer that the version error rather about a cairo, and still I am having a problem with understanding the message: why does it trying to install «0.12.4.1» version, but complains about the «1.2.0» version?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must install the gtk C libraries before you install the Haskell bindings to them. Visit [the installation instructions](http://projects.haskell.org/gtk2hs/download/) and check the section for your operating system if you need instructions on how to do this.